# Reversing the letters in a text file and re-writing them back to the file in same format?

Tags: java

I literally have to take a .java file and reverse the letters so e.g
"Hello world
1234 1233 123"

so its outputs in the file as:

"dlrow olleh
321 3321 4321"

Spaces and lines included.

My program does that kind of, it reverses everything but I cannot get it to format it in the lines

It output is either

> d
>
> l
>
> r
>
> o
>
> w
>
> ....

or

> dlrow olleh 321 3321 4321

Here is my program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Reverse {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {


        File in = new File("C:\\Users\\Ceri\\workspace1\\HelloWorld\\src\\HelloWorld.java");
        Scanner s = new Scanner( in );
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Ceri\\workspace1\\HelloWorld\\src\\HelloWorld.txt");


        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String temp = s.nextLine();
            for (int i = temp.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                out.println(temp.charAt(i));
            }

        }
        s.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }



  }

}
```

Comment: Is it your homework?

Comment: @Andremoniy no but does it matter?

Comment: @user3586915 The 2nd output you mention you're getting doesn't seem possible with the given code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print` instead of `println`. Outside of your loop, you probably want a new line when your scanner reads a new line:

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String temp = s.nextLine();
    for (int i = temp.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        out.print(temp.charAt(i));
    }
    out.println();
}
```

Here's the output I got:

```
321 3321 4321 dlrow olleH
```

...which is a little different than the output you show (which seems to split the letters from the numbers and reverse them separately), but reverses the string in its entirety just fine as you mentioned originally.

Comment: Awesome, this did it!

Cant mark correct for 2 minutes so bare with me and tank you